# Can an expectation value be a function of another expectation value?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space

I've come across the expression (for a 1D free particle) 
$$
\langle{x(t)}\rangle = \frac{t}{m}\langle{p_{x}(t)}\rangle + \langle{x(0)}\rangle 
$$

but what I'm really interested in is $\langle{x(t)^{2}}\rangle$ so that I can calculate $\Delta x$.

I wouldn't expect the momentum to change just because I want $\langle{x(t)^2}\rangle$ instead of $\langle{x(t)}\rangle$, so is it true that

$$
\langle{x(t)^2}\rangle = \frac{t}{m}\langle{p_{x}(t)}\rangle + \langle{x^2(0)}\rangle ?
$$
I think there's a subtlety here that I'm missing.

Comment: Why do you expect the equation for $x$ and $x^2$ to be the same? Would you expect that in classical mechanics?

Comment: One obvious hint that your expression cannot possibly be correct is that the units don't match.

Comment: They are not the same.

Comment: moreover, the lhs is certainly non-negative whereas the rhs could be negative...

Comment: Yes, I know the second equation cannot be correct. What happens to the momentum term?

Comment: Take a look at [Klein 1980](http://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.12300).

Comment: The equation you are seeking is (A11) in that paper, trivially gotten by taking single and double derivatives of first and 2nd moment expectations and utilizing Ehrenfest's theorem.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not currently at University so it may take me a couple of minutes to find the paper online for free.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out $x^2$, the free hamiltonian, and their commutator close under commutation,
$$
 x(t)^2 = e^{itH/\hbar}  x^2(0) e^{-itH/\hbar}= x^2(0)+\frac{it}{\hbar} [H, x^2(0)]-\frac{t^2}{2\hbar^2}[H,[H, x^2(0)]], 
$$ 
where, of course, all terms $O(t^3)$ vanish for the free hamiltonian, $H=p(0)^2/2m= p(t)^2/2m  $.

Hence,

$$
\langle{x(t)^2}\rangle = \langle{x^2(0)}\rangle + \frac{t}{m}\langle \left ( p(0) x(0) + x(0) p(0)\right ) \rangle + \frac{t^2}{m^2}\langle p^2(0)\rangle .  
$$
This is but (A11) of [Klein 1980](http://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.12300). There is hardly any subtlety.

Your $\langle p(t) \rangle $   is really   $\langle p(0) \rangle $, which is conceptually simpler.